# Make python SimpleHTTPServer list subdirectories on top

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I start the server using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

In the browser, I can see the current directory listing by going to 'localhost'. However, it lists them in alphabetical order.

Can I have it in the Windows shell style, with subdirectories listed before files, but both groups individually sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Let me know whether its working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to make changes in SimpleHTTPServer.py file. I made some changes in the below function . You can replace and check

```
def list_directory(self, path):
    """Helper to produce a directory listing (absent index.html).

    Return value is either a file object, or None (indicating an
    error).  In either case, the headers are sent, making the
    interface the same as for send_head().

    """
    lst1=[]
    lst2=[]
    try:
        list = os.listdir(path)
        for i in list:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,i)):
                lst1.append(i)
            elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)):
                lst2.append(i)
    except os.error:
        self.send_error(404, "No permission to list directory")
        return None
    lst1.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
    #print lst1
    #print list
    lst2.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
    f = StringIO()
    displaypath = cgi.escape(urllib.unquote(self.path))
    f.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">')
    f.write("<html>\n<title>Directory listing for %s</title>\n" % displaypath)
    f.write("<body>\n<h2>Directory listing for %s</h2>\n" % displaypath)
    f.write("<hr>\n<ul>\n")
    for name in lst1:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
        displayname = linkname = name
        # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            displayname = name + "/"
            linkname = name + "/"
        f.write('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>\n'
                % (urllib.quote(linkname), cgi.escape(displayname)))
    for name in lst2:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
        displayname = linkname = name
        # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
        if os.path.islink(fullname):
            displayname = name + "@"
            # Note: a link to a directory displays with @ and links with /
        f.write('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>\n'
                % (urllib.quote(linkname), cgi.escape(displayname)))

    f.write("</ul>\n<hr>\n</body>\n</html>\n")
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(length))
    self.end_headers()
    return f
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks Sandeep. I modified your answer slightly to concatenate the 2 lists into 'list' and continue with the original code below that.

Comment: Could you also show how to add a link (like "..") at the top of the list, to point to the parent directory, when we have gone into a sub-directory?

Comment: Good to know :-) i will check about displaying `..` and will let you know